# How to key an HMAC with keys from separate mutually untrusted parties?

Tags: keys, hmac

The problem is as follows:

There are two parties, both of whom would like to HMAC a message with a key. Although the keys are known to one another, both parties do not trust that the other one created a truly random key.

The HMAC result must not be easily attackable by a third party. So it is necessary the final key has substantial entropy whether or not one party didn't supply any.

In an optimistic world, both parties generate cryptographically secure 256-bit random numbers to key the message with.

In a less optimistic world, one party generates a secure 256-bit random number but the other party gives back 256 bits of data with hardly any entropy at all whether due to laziness or malice.

If both parties are lazy and/or malicious (worst case), then we can accept that failure is impossible to avoid. We assume for the problem that at least one party sees a good key as being in their best interest.

What would be the best way to structure an HMAC call so that I can use two keys such that one key being weak only means the strength is lower-bounded by the good key and not completely sabotaged due to some sort of subtlety?

The ideas I have are

- `HMAC(message, key1 || key2)`
- `HMAC(HMAC(message, key1), key2)`
- `HMAC(message, HMAC(key1, key2))`

However, this is starting to feel like one of those problems where there is some subtle issue that I'm probably unaware of with all these seemingly straightforward choices.

**Edit**

After some discussion below, I feel I may need to include some more important details.

Party 1 will hand off an allegedly random 256 bit string to Party 2. Party 2 will also generate an allegedly random 256 bit string. Party 2 will be responsible for generating the HMAC but Party 1 will have the opportunity to reject the result. Both parties know each other's secrets and at least one party cares about having a strong secret although it is possible that the other party is malicious or lazy.

Comment: Are `key1,key2` assumed to be independent? ​ ​ ​

Comment: Yes, key1 and key2 are independent values. Key1 is provided by user 1 and key 2 is provided by user 2.

Comment: Be careful when making this assumption. What happens if user 1 gives user 2 $k_1\in\{0,1\}^{256}$ chosen randomly, and user 2 gives user $k_2=k_1$? In this case, $k_2$ was provided by user 2, but it is *not* independent of $k_1$. What level of hostility can you expect from user 2? Incompetence or malice? If they are totally untrusted, they could simply hand over any keys to a third party. Or are you simply trying to work around the possibility of them using a bad RNG out of ignorance?

Comment: See Stephen Touset's comment. ​ If they _are_ necessarily independent, then $\hspace{1.31 in}$  `HMAC(message, key1 xor key2)` is the best way. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: That's a good point. Although the two users colluding can be ignored as being outside of the problem's scope, one user acting maliciously cannot be. Would using `xor` be weak only in the easy to spot instance of `key1 == key2` or does this weakness have a range associated? I will edit my question with further details that now seem relevant.

Comment: @StephenTouset the level of hostility can be assumed to be fully untrusted. Although both need mutual assurance, neither one should be assumed trustworthy. I have updated the question above.

Comment: If the other side is totally adversarial, there's literally nothing you can do. They can leak any key material whatsoever to a third party. Or they can have a third party provide them whatever data they wish, and authenticate it with the key.

Comment: $k_1=k_2$ is obvious, but such a relationship needn't be. Assuming the key mixing step is XOR as described by @RickyDemer (which is the "correct" answer assuming an incompetent party and not a malicious one), an adversarial party can generate some secret key $k_s$ at random that they share with evil third parties, and set $k_2 = k_1 \oplus k_s$. Now all the malicious users know that the "real" authenticating key is $k_s$, but there is *absolutely no way* for the user acting in faith to know that there's a trivial relationship between $k_1$ and $k_2$.

Comment: Let's say I'm actually keying this message to provide redaction capabilities. User signs `HMAC(msg,key)` instead of `msg` alone and then I store `sig,msg,key` and allow people to verify. Now let's say the user wishes to redact his message. I want to maintain a log of transactions. Therefore I destroy `msg` and `key` but not `sig`. You can't yell something from the roof and then take it back, but I can be obligated to not repeat it. I get to keep the proof that something was said while not holding onto what was said. Because the message may be simple, I want to enforce a level of entropy on it.

Comment: Redaction of this sort is simply impossible on a global level, (if someone sees it, they saw it, that's it) but the goal is that I'm not on the hook whether morally or legally for continuing to host the message by continuing to host signed transaction information. A lot of messages would be easily attackable if the signature was just of `Hash(msg)` because the message-space would be predictable and of low entropy and I'm trying to get around that.

Comment: Doing some more research and it seems like running `SHA256(k1 || k2)` maybe be fine for my purposes. If both keys have 256 bits of entropy, I just bound myself to 255. If one key has 256 bits of entropy and the other has effectively 0, I still bound myself to 255. The only way I would ever go below 255 bits of entropy is if both parties failed to produce good keys (excluded from my requirements). Is there any way one party could lower that entropy bound by controlling half the pre-image? Or is that entropy in the pre-image only additive in this case, with the hash function bounding it?

Comment: Why does that bind you to 255? $\;$

Comment: Well, if you have one person supplying at least 256 bits of entropy, the other person cannot supply negative entropy AFAIK (this I suppose is my question). If you have (256+0) in a worst case and hash it with SHA256, wouldn't it be 255 bits of entropy? And in the best case, both supply 256 bits of entropy totaling 512 bits, but the hashing reduces that entropy down to 255. But never having less that 256 bits of input entropy per the problem specs, you can't end up with less.

Comment: @SamuelHorwitz, hashing a 256-bit input with full entropy does indeed reduce the outputs by almost half due to collisions, but if the hash is strong the attacker has no way to make use of that, since they would have to try every input to know which outputs are possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just concatenate.

Two 256-bit keys lead to a 512-bit key which is short enough for HMAC with common hash functions to use as is. XOR would allow the second party to easily choose a related key (and has worse behavior when neither key is perfectly random). Hashing and double HMAC use more resources without a clear benefit, unless you care about the size of the key, in which case hashing would be the way to go.

If you had longer/more keys, concatenation would become equivalent to hashing, because HMAC internally hashes keys that are longer than block size (512+ bits for all SHA-x).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As you may have seen above, the comments forced me to think more about what I really want. If I have X number of strings and I know that at least one of them has 256 bits of entropy, can I assume the entropy lower bound of the concatenation of all strings is 256 bits of entropy? Or is it possible for someone to somehow contribute "negative entropy" in a way that by concatenating their string it actually lowers the total entropy? I feel like the answer is "no", but I'm scared of "obvious" answers in crypto and want to make sure.

Comment: @SamuelHorwitz, if one of the values has 256 bits of entropy then the concatenated value cannot reduce that.